# GoLang defining methods on object receiver behaves wrong, but pointer receiver

Tags: go

I have an interface named `Being`, which requires two methods `SetValue(v int)` and `GetValue() int`. Then I have a base class `Animal` implementing it, and further a subclass `Cat` inherited from `Animal`.

Following is the code ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AT3Gp9UCTI)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Being interface {
    SetValue(v int)
    GetValue() int
}

type Animal struct {
    value int
}

type Cat struct {
    Animal
}

func (a Animal) SetValue(v int) {
    a.value = v
}

func (a Animal) GetValue() int {
    return a.value
}

func MakeCat() Being {
    return Cat{}
}

func main() {
    cat := MakeCat()
    cat.SetValue(1)
    fmt.Println(cat.GetValue()) 
}
```

However, the output is `0`, rather than `1`.

If I slightly modify the code to this ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/90_Q8Pmb8D)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Being interface {
    SetValue(v int)
    GetValue() int
}

type Animal struct {
    value int
}

type Cat struct {
    Animal
}

//Change the receiver to a pointer
func (a *Animal) SetValue(v int) {
    a.value = v
}

func (a Animal) GetValue() int {
    return a.value
}

//Return the pointer
func MakeCat() Being {
    cat := Cat{}
    return &cat
}

func main() {
    cat := MakeCat()
    cat.SetValue(1)
    fmt.Println(cat.GetValue()) 
}
```

where the modifications are marked by comments, the code behaves correctly, and output `1`.

I cannot think of the reason of such phenomena, could anyone help?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you set a field on a copy of the object?

Comment: @BenVoigt are you saying in the first approach calling SetValue on cat is calling on a copy of it?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers  "called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's the definition of passing a value), so changes it makes will be invisible to the caller"

Comment: @BenVoigt, i see, thanks!